# MySQL filtering out a criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I thought this is simple with you guys here, but a little bit hard for me to figure out how to do this. I have tried but did not get the result so wanted to consult every one here.

Here I have three columns: state, store, laptop_brand
I wanted to filter out how many store have the amount of HP < 3 ( group by State).

My idea on this is like this:

`SELECT state, count(laptop_brand) 
 FROM sample_survey 
 WHERE count(select store from sample_survey where laptop_brand = "HP") <3       group by state`

but I could not make it real.
[sample_survey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YkM7.png)
Attached pic snippet data for your reference.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Show us the expected result as well (with the sample data as defined.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Try this:

```
SELECT state, store, count(laptop_brand) as total_laptop

FROM sample_survey

WHERE laptop_brand = "HP"

GROUP BY state, store

HAVING count(laptop_brand)<3
```

Comment: Thanks you all. I forgot the HAVING clause which could solve my concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Out the second codition in a having clause like this

```
SELECT state, count(laptop_brand) as cnt
FROM sample_survey 
WHERE laptop_brand = "HP" group by state HAVING cnt <3
```